# Bitstype creation

Tags: types, type-conversion, julia

How can I use `bitstype`?

I have tried `Base.box`/`Base.unbox` but they didn't work. I have read that `reinterpret` should be used. It worked:

```
bitstype 32 Blah32
blah32 = reinterpret(Blah32, 8)
# Blah32(0x00000008)
```

However, using this method, I cannot create `bitstype` with, for example, 2048 bits.

How can I use `bitstype` to create types that contains arbitrary number of bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a memory block that is big enough for the reinterpret to work.

```
bitstype 2048 Blah2048
blah2048 = reinterpret(Blah2048, [1:32])

 1-element Array{Blah2048,1}:
 Blah2048(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)
```

It would be nice if you provided the error you got when you said that it does not work. `BoundsError()` is actually quite informative, because it indicates that you are reading memory outside the 64 bits of a normal integer.

Also. Why do you want to create such big bits types? Your processor does not support them, so they have to be emulated. Depending on your usage you might be able to write your code faster without that extra layer of abstraction.

Comment: 2048 bits was just a random number that can be divided by 8(version 0.2 requirements). I haven't included errors for `box`/`unbox` because I thought they shouldn't be used. Also, you have minor error in your stanza: `blah2048 = reinterpret(Blah2048, [1:64])`. After that, it works. Thank you.

Comment: If you are on a 32 bit system, you will definetly need 64 32 bit integers instead of 32 64 bit integers to get 2048 bit in total.